# How to remove top bar in a desktop PWA window in standalone mode?

Tags: macos, google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm in the process of moving a Chrome App to a Progressive Web App that runs on desktops.

So far, from Chrome I can install using the `Add to Applications` action and start it by clicking the created icon. While I can resize the window using `window.resizeTo` in JavaScript, running on a Macbook, my app is framed with the actions top bar that comes with applications :

[image]

In Chrome Apps, this bar can be removed by passing `frame: "none"` in the window creation function (`chrome.app.window.create()`), I wonder if there is a `manifest.json` option, Service Worker or simple JavaScript code to achieve the same thing, if that is ever possible.

Here is the `manifest.json` file I'm using :

```
{
  "short_name": "My App",
  "name": "The name of My App",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/myapp-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/?launchscreen=true"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's officially launched by Chrome yet so you'd be better off filing a bug with them.

Comment: That would be nice, so it will feel more native